# Etherscan showing 0 holders

Tags: etherscan

I created an ERC20 token and deployed it using Remix IDE. My smart contract is available here: https://etherscan.io/address/0xdacD69347dE42baBfAEcD09dC88958378780FB62#code

I assigned all available tokens to me, and I can see it in my MetaMask[image: metamask screenshot]

However, when I take a look at the token page on etherscan, I see that holders value is set to 0 addresses.

You can see the etherscan page here: https://etherscan.io/token/0xdacD69347dE42baBfAEcD09dC88958378780FB62

I'm wondering how is this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Etherscan likely only tracks balances of accounts that have had `Transfer` events to or from their address. Since your token doesn't emit a Transfer event when it assigns the `totalSupply` to your account when you create the token, Etherscan isn't tracking it. All you have to do is do a `Transfer` of any amount of your token (0 is fine as well) to or from the account in question and Etherscan should begin tracking that account